# Show $\{e^{2\pi ik\sqrt{2}}:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in the unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, roots-of-unity

> Show $\{e^{2\pi ik\sqrt{2}}:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in the unit circle.

This fact was mentioned to me in the comment on another post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2451876/).  I've tried but I cannot prove it.  I was hoping to work out for myself whether this is the unique power of $1$ having this property... but I fell before even the first hurdle.

I began by taking roots of unity and raising to the power of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$; the results are invariably on the unit circle as would be expected.  But I rather thought given statement implied every root of unit raised to the power of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ would equal $1$; which I did not find.  Clearly I am missing something (or many things).

Comment: Note: $1^{\sqrt{2}}$ is not a good notation for the set $\{ \exp(2\pi i k\sqrt{2}) : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Note that $G_{\alpha} = \{ \exp (2\pi i k \alpha) : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subgroup of the unit circle, for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. What do you know about the closed subgroups of the unit circle?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How should a single number be dense in infinitly large set?

Comment: @JesseMadnick well to me a set is dense in another if every element of the 2nd set in the first is either a member or a limit point of the first.

Comment: @CarlMummert well the point is I don't understand the statement either. The comment is in the comments of the linked question which perhaps provides context?  To conjecture what was meant; I thought what was meant is that there are multiple numbers satisfying that expression.

Comment: @DanielFischer I know that the unit circle can be expressed as the circle group $\mathbb{T}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\lvert z\rvert=1\}$ but not so much about subgroups

Comment: @Robert Frost: presumably they meant the result that Daniel Fischer mentioned in another comment.  Indeed, my reading of the comment in the other thread was that the person was arguing that the notation "$1^{\sqrt{2}}$" should not be used for this set, as a way of showing why the notation $1^{1/n}$ in the original post should similarly not be used to refer to a set of roots of unity.

Comment: @CarlMummert ok thanks. Am I right in thinking I have fully eliminated the bad notation in that question?

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks so it looks like the intended statement is that $\{e^{2\pi ik\sqrt{2}}:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in the unit circle?  If so I will correct the question.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek my thoughts exactly!

Comment: Yes, that's the only somewhat reasonable interpretation of "$1^{\sqrt{2}}$" I can think of that would make the assertion of denseness meaningful and true.

Comment: @DanielFischer ok thanks. I don't think it was inaccurate analogy to my original dreadful notation although I get the point now.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_rotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $\newcommand{\euler}{\mathrm{e}}\newcommand{\ie}{\mathrm{i}}$Show $\{\euler^{2\ie\pi k\sqrt{2}}:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in the unit circle.

First note that

- the mapping $\euler^{\ie (.)}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ is
  uniformly continuous $$|\euler^{\ie t} - \euler^{\ie s}| \leq
     \sqrt{2} |t-s|.$$
- For every irrational number $\alpha$, for every $\epsilon>0$,
  and for every $C>0$ there exists a fraction $\frac{n}{m}$ such that $0<|\alpha -
     \frac{n}{m}|< \epsilon$, $m > C$ and $\gcd(n,m) = 1$.
- For every $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $C>0$
  such that for every $d \in \mathbb{Z}$, $d\geq C$ there exists a $c
     \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $$\left|\frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}\right| <
     \epsilon$$

$\newcommand{\z}{\zeta}$Now let $\z \in \mathbb{T}$ then there exists a $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\z = \euler^{\ie t} = \euler^{2\ie\pi \frac{t}{2\pi}}$ and fix $\epsilon>0$. Furthermore there is a fraction $\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\left|\frac{a}{b} - \frac{t}{2\pi}\right|< \epsilon$. Let $C>0$ be such that is satisfies point three of the stated facts for $a,b$. Since $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational we use fact two and obtain
a fraction $\frac{n}{m}$ such that $$m>C,\quad \gcd(m,n)=1 \quad\text{and}\quad 0<\left|\sqrt{2} -\frac{n}{m}\right|< \epsilon$$
Since $\gcd(m,n)=1$ there are by the euclidean algorithm $r_1,r_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$r_1 n + r_2 m = 1$$
From fact point three there is a $c$ such that $\left|\frac{a}{b} - \frac{c}{m}\right|< \epsilon$.

Choose $k=cr_1$ then
$$\euler^{2\ie\pi k \frac{n}{m}} = \euler^{2\ie\pi  \frac{cr_1 n}{m}}
= \euler^{2\ie\pi  \frac{c-cr_2 m}{m}} = \euler^{2\ie\pi  \frac{c}{m}} \underbrace{\euler^{2\ie\pi  \frac{cr_2 m}{m}}}_{=1} = \euler^{2\ie\pi  \frac{c}{m}}
$$
From fact point one and the triangular inequality we obtain
$$\left|\euler^{2\ie\pi k \sqrt{2}}-\z\right|
\leq
\left|\euler^{2\ie\pi k \sqrt{2}}-\euler^{2\ie\pi k \frac{n}{m}}\right|
+
\left|\euler^{2\ie\pi k \frac{n}{m}}-\euler^{2\ie\pi \frac{a}{b}}\right|
+
\left|\euler^{2\ie\pi \frac{a}{b}}-\z\right| \leq 3\sqrt{2} \epsilon$$
which proves the claim.

Comment: In the upper bound $|e^{it} - e^{i s}| \leq
   \sqrt{2} |t-s|$, the factor $\sqrt2$ is not necessary.

Comment: the factor $\sqrt{2}$ appears accidentally. you are right

Comment: Just returning to this question I now know another proof which i have also added as an aswer - does it look right to you?

Comment: @it'sahirecarbaby maybe you could specify what you mean by 'until we are in the interval'. Because I am not sure what you mean. Then also I cannot follow your conclusion that 'otherwise the orbit must be periodic'. This is probably because I did not understand the first statement in question. I can only guess that you want to establish some connection with the decimal representation. Then periodicity would lead to a rational number. However, I am not sure if you got this direction correctly.

Comment: Thanks for looking @NathanaelSkrepek .  I clarified what I meant by "in the interval".  I see now that my proof is essentially the same as yours, but with less detail and framed slightly differently.  It is a corollary of your proof that every irrational orbit is dense in the unit interval. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_rotation

Answer (score -1):

Just returning to this question after a long time... I have in the interim learned that an **irrational orbit** is dense in the unit circle, which is fairly obvious.

An irrational orbit is one homeomorphic to $x\mapsto x+y\pmod1$ on the unit interval, with $y$ irrational.  Every such orbit will be dense because for any arbitrarily narrow interval $[0,\delta)$ of our choosing, we can repeat the irrational addition until we are in the aforementioned arbitrarily narrow interval, otherwise our orbit must be periodic with period a whole number multiple of $1/\delta$, which contradicts irrationality of $y$.

Therefore we get an instant proof because the map on the unit circle induced by $k\mapsto k+1$ is topologically conjugate to $x\mapsto x+\log(\sqrt2)$ on the unit interval, which is irrational by Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem.