# $\{z^{n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $|z|=1$ and $z = e^{2\pi\dot\iota\theta}$, where $\theta\in\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, then $\{z^{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in the unit circle.

I tried to prove that, for any $w$ on the unit circle there exist an $n \in N$ such that $|z^{n}-w| $ $<$ $\epsilon$ for given $\epsilon > 0$. I don't know how to proceed, may be the denseness of irrationals to be used but I didn't get how to do that.
Please help me to crack this problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469586